# 1-Dimensional Plots with Java

Tags: java, graphics

I've never used Java for graphics before so I am currently trying to learn.

As a basic exercise, I want to plot points contained in an array onto a number line but am not sure how to get started.

I am doing the following to draw the line:

```
public void drawNumberLine(Graphics g) {
    g.drawLine(0,0,100,0);
}
```

Not sure where to go from there since I don't know how I will be able to plot the points on the line. I've read a few tutorials but all dealt with 2D plots so I was wondering if someone can direct me in the right direction.

Comment: A 1 dimensional plot is a single point.

Comment: I guess he wants to plot points on a line, i.e. something like `--|-----|-----`.

Comment: @Roflcoptr - A 0 dimensional plot is a single point, a 1 dimensional plot is a line.

Comment: @Ishtar I really dont think that your statement is true.

Comment: @Roflcoptr - It's not an opinion it **is** true, unless you mean something different with [dimension](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimension)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What number range is your array? I'm assuming you want to scale it down to fit your 100 long line? Is it only positive numbers? In that case, something like this should work

```
//Find the max value for scaling purposes
double max = Double.MIN_VALUE;
double min = Double.MAX_VALUE
for(double i : array){
    if(i > max) max = i;
    if(i < min) min = i;
}


for(double i : array){
    //Replace 100 with a variable for how long the line is!
    double scaled = ((i-min)/(max-min)) * 100; 

    Ellipse.Double circle = new EllipseDouble(width, height, scaled, 0);

    g2d.draw(circle)
}
```

If it is an int array, make sure to avoid integer division.

Comment: I used what you gave and tweaked it a bit and it worked fine! Thank you!

Comment: I've just noticed that you seem unaware of the accept answer button :) You should go through your previous questions as well, and mark the questions that helped you the most as an accepted answer! :) (It's the checkbox under the up/down arrows on the side of the post)

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you have a size of the base line, e.g. 100 pixels, and a start value, e.g. 0 pixels, you can calculate the exact pixel where to draw some marker for the point.

Example:

Line represents integers 10 to 20 and is drawn from 50 to 150 pixels:

```
x_offset = 50
lower_bound = 10
width = 100 pixels //(150 - 50)
range = 10 //(20 - 10)
pixels_per_step = width/range = 100/10 = 10
```

Thus, each integer marker i would be drawn at

```
x = x_offset + pixels_per_step * (i - lower_bound) => (replace constants)
x = 50 + 10 * (i - 10) => (example for i = 15)
x = 50 + 10 * (15 - 10) = 50 + 10 * 5 = 50 + 50 = 100 => draw marker 15 at 100 pixels
```

This should get you started. Note that you might have to round if `pixels_per_step` or `i`is not an integer.